# prev part is not working in carousel even though the next part is working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

this is the snippet of the code I have written using bootstrap.

```
<div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
      <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
      <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
      <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
      <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
    </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

the id and href should be the same and I have already done but still, the results are the same. the problem is that instead of working as a prev button it redirects to a new page.

Comment: Did the answer solve Your problem? :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Your code You miss to close first `div` => `div id="testimonial-carousel"`, in first `<a>` tag missing `#` in `href` properties and it's better to add `bootstrap4` [template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/) If You use this version obviously.
Lastly If You need to run this carousel (automatic) You need to change `data-ride="false"`
to `data-ride="carousel"`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <h2>I love all dogs, regardless of breed</h2>
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561037404-61cd46aa615b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="dog-profile">
        <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, because of me! Instead of going for a walk with my pet,I eat garbage and watch zombie TV</h2>
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587300003388-59208cc962cb?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="lady-profile">
        <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-primary"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-primary"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```